# Getting Array of Array of Objects instead of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 array of objects (this.so, model) that I'm trying to manipulate to create a new array of objects (this.soModelBOMs).

I used array.filter().map() on both arrays.

However, I'm getting an Array of Array of Objects instead of just an Array of Objects.

```
this.soModelBOMs = this.so.filter(x => x.lacking > 0).map(so => 
    model.filter(x => x.model_no == so.model_no).map(m => ({
        production_id: so.production_id,
        model_id: m.model_id,
        model_no: m.model_no,
        process_rev: m.process_rev,
        bom_rev: m.bom_rev,
        process: m.process.map(p => ({
            process_order: p.process_order,
            process_name: p.process_name,
            process_no: p.process_no,
            process_yield: p.process_yield,
            bom: p.bom.map(b => ({
                alt: b.alt,
                bom_item: b.bom_item,
                bom_name: b.bom_name,
                bom_code: b.bom_code,
                bom_qty: b.bom_qty,
                bom_stock: b.bom_stock,
                bom_yield: b.bom_yield,
                bom_req: b.bom_qty * so.lacking
            }))
        }))
    }))
)
```

I'm getting something like these:

```
[
  [
    {
      "production_id": 1,
      "model_id": 1,
      ...
    }
  ],
    {
      "production_id": 2,
      "model_id": 2,
      ...
    }
  [
    {
      "production_id": 3,
      "model_id": 3,
      ...
    }
  ],
]
```

How do I fix my code so that I can sort of just push the objects into the array instead of pushing the arrays of objects into the array?

Something like this:

```
[
    {
      "production_id": 1,
      "model_id": 1,
      ...
    },
    {
      "production_id": 2,
      "model_id": 2,
      ...
    },
    {
      "production_id": 3,
      "model_id": 3,
      ...
    }
]
```

Comment: There are so many `map` function and each of them will return a new array

Comment: Its not a duplicate. The reason why I'm getting an array of array is because of the map() function. I need to eliminate that and use the correct method.

Comment: Alright, although given the question it makes sense to me to flatten the array you have in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `find` instead of `filter`.

```
this.soModelBOMs = this.so.filter(x => x.lacking > 0).map(so => {
var m = model.find(x => x.model_no == so.model_no);
if(m) {
    return {
        production_id: so.production_id,
        model_id: m.model_id,
        model_no: m.model_no,
        process_rev: m.process_rev,
        bom_rev: m.bom_rev,
        process: m.process.map(p => ({
            process_order: p.process_order,
            process_name: p.process_name,
            process_no: p.process_no,
            process_yield: p.process_yield,
            bom: p.bom.map(b => ({
                alt: b.alt,
                bom_item: b.bom_item,
                bom_name: b.bom_name,
                bom_code: b.bom_code,
                bom_qty: b.bom_qty,
                bom_stock: b.bom_stock,
                bom_yield: b.bom_yield,
                bom_req: b.bom_qty * so.lacking
            }))
        }))
    };
}
})
```

I didn't test this code though.

P.S:

You could refactor your code with `spread operator` to something like this

```js
this.soModelBOMs = this.so.filter(x => x.lacking > 0).map(so => {
  var m = model.find(x => x.model_no == so.model_no);
  if (m) {
    return {
      ...so,
      ...m,
      process: m.process.map(p =>
        ({
          ...p,
          bom: p.bom.map(b =>
            ({ ...b,
              bom_req: b.bom_qty * so.lacking
            }))
        })),
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, it worked! I wonder if there's a better version. Someone said the used of spread operator. I wonder if the reduce() function can also work here.

Comment: Ya. you could use spread operator if you use ES6. you can replace the whole object literal with a spread operator as i can see

Comment: Something like this  `this.soModelBOMs = this.so.filter(x => x.lacking > 0).map(so => {
   var m = model.find(x => x.model_no == so.model_no);
    if(m) {
        return { ...so, ...m };
    }
})`

Comment: And also, seems to me those calls to `map` inside the object are useless because you return an object with same properties and values as the parameter

Comment: I needed to modify some properties and add properties that's why I had to use map. But yeah, if I'm creating a new object then that may not make sense. I'm still learning though.